# If I buy V-Bucks, can I use them on other devices?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

If I buy V-Bucks on my mobile, will they be saved on my Switch and PS4 too? Or if I buy them on Switch, will they save on my mobile and PS4 too?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the account and platform you used to buy them.
According to Epic's [FAQ](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/faq):

> **Q**: *Are my V-Bucks bound to the platform I purchase them on?*
>
> **A**: Purchased V-Bucks are shared between PC and mobile if you've linked your account with your Epic ID. However, V-Bucks purchased on PlayStation 4, Xbox One, or Switch are not shared between other platforms.

So, in your case, having bought them on your mobile, **no, you cannot use them on your Switch and PS4**.